# Dynamically update a multi-column list while positioning around other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly, I apologize for the title of this post, I'm not really sure how to put into words what I want, so maybe these pictures will help.

This is what I want the final outcome to look like:

[image]

This is where I'm stuck at:

[image]

I have a bunch of JS objects that contain a variable amount of "branded" and "generic" products, so the size of each list varies according to which country is being called. The problem comes from when I have a large amount of "generic" products because after the first column they're styled to spill over into the next column, and at most a third. However, I need these "spillover" list items to get pushed to the top of the available space.

I've tried to `position: absolute` my lists, and dynamically update the top spacing for the generic list using this:

`$('ul#genericList li:first-type-of').css('top', $('#branded').height());`

but I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: first-type-of`

I've created the best **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/46ek5/6/)** I could without including too much stuff that isn't important.

My HTML for this is pretty straight forward:

```
<div class="modalInner">
    <div id="branded">
        <p>BRANDED</p>
        <ul id="brandedList"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="generic">
        <p>GENERIC</p>
        <ul id="genericList"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
.modal {

    ul {
        top:0;
        margin:0;
        padding-left:0;
        z-index:101;
    }

    ul#genericList {
        position:relative;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;

        li:first-of-type {
            top:0; //height of branded list
        }

        li:last-of-type {
            padding-top:149px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @imtheman I threw together a fiddle for you

Comment: Never type in uppercase, use `text-transform: uppercase` instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46ek5/1/)). And better use `margin: auto` to center ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46ek5/4/)), because with `position:absolute` it is cut if window isn't wide enough

Comment: @Oriol okay... but can you help me with my actual issue?

Comment: @BadDog I think the only way to do the columns is [Multi columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) (`column-count: 3`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46ek5/7/)), but I don't know how to place `.map` at the top of the third column. I tried floating, but with `column-count` is like `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't much you can do with columns because there is no concept of paddings or margins for the column model.

I'd suggest using other ways to create columns of your own so you can have more control of the positioning. I created a solution using `display:inline-block` and `width:33%;`. Not the prettiest solution, but I think it'll help you find you're looking for.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46ek5/22/.

As for `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: first-type-of`, the selector should be `:first-of-type`.

Column Model: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few different options here.

I use bootstrap because it comes with some of this stuff built in.

[jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/melaniersumner/jLvqH/) http://jsfiddle.net/melaniersumner/jLvqH/

Use a script to dynamically append the list item to the appropriate list, and base it on a counter. Once the list hits the X count, then append the list items to the next list, etc.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```